# How would I delete lines from a tabular text file using python?

Tags: python, file, io, tabular, del

I am going through tabular text files (.txt), and I am wondering what is the best way to delete lines on a text file that have entries with either negative numbers or blank entries?

This is my current code, but the main question comes in what python code will write from the file, only valid lines (lines in the text file that do not contain a negative number or a blank entry.) When I run this script, it still writes all the text file entries despite the conditions set.

```
import os, sys

inFile = sys.argv[1]
baseN = os.path.basename(inFile)
outFile = 'c:/exampleSolution.txt'

#if path exists, read and write file
if os.path.exists(inFile):
    inf = open(inFile,'r')
    outf = open(outFile,'w')

    #reading and writing header
    header = inf.readline()
    outf.write(header)

    not_consider = []

    lines = inf.read().splitlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        data = lines[i].split(' ')
        for j in range(0,len(data)):
            if (data[j] == '' or int(data[j]) < 0):
                #if line is having blank or negtive value
                # append i value to the not_consider list

                leaveOut.append(i)

    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        #if i is in not_consider list, don't write to out file
        if i not in leaveOut:
            outf.write(lines[i])
            print(lines[i])
            outf.write("\n")

    inf.close()
    outf.close()
```

This is an example of a file input I am working with:

[screenshot of part of the chart I'm working with, in this example, I would delete site no's 2 and 4 for having a negative number and/or missing items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpjbf.png)

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Comment: Is your file tab-separated? Then the `.split(" ")` would do nothing. Try `"a\tbc\td".split(" ")` to see that. If so, try `.split("\t")`.